Is there a commutative ring with unity, zero divisors and only trivial ideals?
I know this question can't be true, otherwise we have a maximal ideal $\{0\}$ that's not prime. My textbook has the following
Theorem. In a commutative ring with unity, all maximal ideals are prime.
And I'm exactly trying to prove this theorem and arriving at this "counterexample." So is there such a ring, and could you explain the reasons without relying on the above theorem? Don't spoil the theorem; I want to prove it myself.

Well, in a given commutative ring $R$, a zero divisor $z$ can't be invertible, so $1 \not\in Rz$, meaning that $Rz$ is a non-trivial ideal as soon as $z \neq 0$.

@ZiruiWang are you only using commutative rings? If so, you should say so. If you aren't using commutative rings, then you may be using the wrong definition of "prime ideal."  If you are using commutative rings the answer is trivially "no" and if you are using noncommutative rings the answer is trivially "yes." (That is, given no more context about what kind of "ring" you mean.)

Sorry for the omission; I edited my question. Wow, you guys surely know a lot! I wonder where you have learned facts such as "a zero divisor can't be invertible"? When I face a new theorem, my brain is quite blank.

@ZiruiWang otherwise we have a maximal ideal {0} that's not prime. Why do you say that? Sometimes ${0}$ is prime, sometimes it isn't.

@ZiruiWang How long have you been learning the subject? I think most students would have encountered "a zero divisor cannot be invertible" before the end of their first course on the topic.

@rschwieb There are zero divisors $a\ne0,b\ne0$ but $ab=0$. So $ab\in I$ but $a\notin I,b\notin I$, where $I={0}$. So $I$ is not prime. My first contact with abstract algebra was a 3-day crash course, which taught me very little ring theory. Now I'm following a 3-month MOOC from a top Chinese university, which is more extensive and more difficult. I've done the first 2 months so far.

@ZiruiWang Ok, from what you've said I can now tell you are assuming your rings are commutative.  Then yes, you are right that the answer to "is there a commutative ring with nontrivial zero divisors but only trivial ideals?" is "no" because having only trivial ideals would imply ${0}$ is maximal and so also prime, but this contradicts the fact that there are nonzero zero divisors.  Another way to say this is that a commutative ring with only trivial ideals is a domain, but more strongly you can say it is a field

@ZiruiWang Could you share the MOOC webpage? I am very curious :)

@rschwieb https://www.icourse163.org/course/NJU-1462062161

@ZiruiWang Thanks
